# Cannot evaluate conditional breakpoint in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have a really really frustrating error in Visual Studio 2017

I am running code via NUnit tests and get the error below

> The condition for a breakpoint failed to execute.
>   The condition was 'value == 22'.
>   The error returned was 'Evaluation of method System.Decimal.op_Equality() calls into native method System.AppDomain.GetId().
>   Evaluation of native methods in this context is not supported.'.
>   Click OK to stop at this breakpoint

Can anyone help please? I have tried with managed compatibility on and off neither work.

If I have managed compatibility off, I can't debug anything at all.

```
public decimal MyValue
{
    get => _value;
    set
    {
        if (_value == value)
        {
            return;
        }

    _value = value;
    HasChanged = true;
}
```

Paul

Comment: Try `decimal.Equals()` instead of the `==` operator?

Comment: The condition for a breakpoint failed to execute. The condition was '(decimal.Equals(22M))'. The error returned was 'error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'decimal.Equals(decimal)''. Click OK to stop at this breakpoint.

Comment: I tried value.Equals(22) and get the same error

Comment: Just change code to add `if (value == 22) { /* empty line for breakpoint */}` temporary...

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple reports similar to this issue in developer community of visual studio. In one of them it is stated as;

> We have fixed the problem in the upcoming preview of Visual Studio 2019. Thank you for your feedback!

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/314822/the-condition-for-a-breakpoint-failed-to-execute-e.html

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/377921/evaluation-of-native-methods-in-this-context-is-no.html

It looks like this bug in the debugger exists for more than a year

Comment: @Paul why? Preview seem to be out - https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/

Answer (score 0):

if you use a single equals sign in the conditional expression, it works.  If you use two equal signs (like in C#), it won't.

`iFcn == 2 // generates error message`

`iFcn = 2 //works great`

(using VS 2019)

Hope this helps.

Comment: A single = is an assignment, not a comparison.